# Use a subquery to reject certain records - MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query in which I want to return certain results given that something has happend and reject others where something has happened and further yet reject others where something has NOT happened.

Here is current example output:

```
VISIT ID | MRN | ORD NUM | ORD STS | ORD DESC
123456   | 123 | 987654  | ACTIVE  | URINE TEST
123456   | 123 | 987654  | IN PROG | URINE TEST
123456   | 123 | 987654  | COMPLETE| URINE TEST
123456   | 123 | 987321  | ACTIVE  | INSERT FOLEY
123456   | 123 | 987321  | IN PROG | INSERT FOLEY
123456   | 123 | 987321  | COMPLETE| INSERT FOLEY
124578   | 321 | 654321  | ACTIVE  | URINE TEST
124578   | 321 | 654321  | IN PROG | URINE TEST
124578   | 321 | 654321  | COMPLETE| URINE TEST
END OF REPORT
```

My desired output is the following:

```
VISIT ID | MRN | ORD NUM | ORD STS | ORD DESC
123456   | 123 | 987654  | ACTIVE  | URINE TEST
123456   | 123 | 987654  | IN PROG | URINE TEST
123456   | 123 | 987654  | COMPLETE| URINE TEST
123456   | 123 | 987321  | ACTIVE  | INSERT FOLEY
123456   | 123 | 987321  | IN PROG | INSERT FOLEY
123456   | 123 | 987321  | COMPLETE| INSERT FOLEY
END OF REPORT
```

I only want to see visit ids that have a urine test if they also have either an `INSERT FOLEY` order OR/AND a `REMOVE FOLEY` order. So if I come in and only get a urine test, then I should not show up on the report.

Here is my query:

```
-- FOLEY CATHETER ORDERS

-- VARIABLE DECLARATION AND INITIALIZATION
DECLARE @SD DATETIME
DECLARE @ED DATETIME
SET @SD = '2013-06-01';
SET @ED = '2013-06-30';

-- COLUMN SELECTION
SELECT PV.PtNo_Num AS 'VISIT ID'
, PV.Med_Rec_No AS 'MRN'
, PV.vst_start_dtime AS 'ADMIT'
, PV.vst_end_dtime AS 'DISC'
, PV.Days_Stay AS 'LOS'
, PV.pt_type AS 'PT TYPE'
, PV.hosp_svc AS 'HOSP SVC'
, SO.ord_no AS 'ORDER NUMBER'
--, SO.ent_dtime AS 'ORDER ENTRY TIME'
--, DATEDIFF(HOUR,PV.vst_start_dtime,SO.ent_dtime) AS 'ADM TO ENTRY HOURS'
, CASE
    WHEN SO.svc_desc = 'INSERT FOLEY CATHETER' THEN 'INSERT FOLEY'
    WHEN SO.svc_desc = 'INSERT INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER TO GRAVITY DRAINAGE' THEN 'INSERT FOLEY'
    WHEN SO.svc_desc = 'REMOVE INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER' THEN 'REMOVE FOLEY'
    ELSE SO.svc_desc
  END AS 'ORD DESC'
, CASE
    WHEN OSM.ord_sts = 'ACTIVE' THEN '1 - ACTIVE'
    WHEN OSM.ord_sts = 'IN PROGRESS' THEN '2 - IN PROGRESS'
    WHEN OSM.ord_sts = 'COMPLETE' THEN '3 - COMPLETE'
    WHEN OSM.ord_sts = 'CANCEL' THEN '4 - CANCEL'
    WHEN OSM.ord_sts = 'DISCONTINUE' THEN '5 - DISCONTINUE'
    WHEN OSM.ord_sts = 'SUSPEND' THEN '6 - SUSPEND'
  END AS 'ORDER STATUS'
, SOS.prcs_dtime AS 'ORDER STATUS TIME'
, DATEDIFF(DAY,PV.vst_start_dtime,SOS.prcs_dtime) AS 'ADM TO ORD STS IN DAYS'

-- DB(S) USED
FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V PV
JOIN smsmir.sr_ord SO
ON PV.PtNo_Num = SO.episode_no
JOIN smsmir.sr_ord_sts_hist SOS
ON SO.ord_no = SOS.ord_no
JOIN smsmir.ord_sts_modf_mstr OSM
ON SOS.hist_sts = OSM.ord_sts_modf_cd

-- FILTER(S)
WHERE PV.Adm_Date BETWEEN @SD AND @ED
AND (SO.svc_desc LIKE 'INSERT FOLEY CATHETER'
    OR SO.svc_desc LIKE 'INSERT INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER TO GRAVITY DRAINAGE'
    OR SO.svc_desc LIKE 'REMOVE INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER'
    OR SO.svc_desc LIKE 'URIN%'
    )
-- TRYING TO KICK OUT PATIENTS WHO DID NOT GET A FOLEY CATHETER ORDER
-- OF ANY TYPE
--AND PV.PtNo_Num NOT IN (
--    SELECT SO.ord_no

--   FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V PV
--  JOIN smsmir.sr_ord SO
--  ON PV.PtNo_Num = SO.episode_no
--  JOIN smsmir.sr_ord_sts_hist SOS
--  ON SO.ord_no = SOS.ord_no
--  JOIN smsmir.ord_sts_modf_mstr OSM
--  ON SOS.hist_sts = OSM.ord_sts_modf_cd

--  WHERE (SO.svc_desc != 'INSERT FOELY CATHETER'
--        OR SO.svc_desc != 'INSERT INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER TO GRAVITY DRAINAGE'
--        OR SO.svc_desc != 'REMOVE INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER'
--        )
--)
-- KICKS OUT DISCONTINUED ORDERS
AND SO.ord_no NOT IN (
    SELECT SO.ord_no

    FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V PV
    JOIN smsmir.sr_ord SO
    ON PV.PtNo_Num = SO.episode_no
    JOIN smsmir.sr_ord_sts_hist SOS
    ON SO.ord_no = SOS.ord_no
    JOIN smsmir.ord_sts_modf_mstr OSM
    ON SOS.hist_sts = OSM.ord_sts_modf_cd

    WHERE OSM.ord_sts = 'DISCONTINUE'
    AND (SO.svc_desc LIKE 'INSERT FOLEY CATHETER'
    OR SO.svc_desc LIKE 'INSERT INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER TO GRAVITY DRAINAGE'
    OR SO.svc_desc LIKE 'REMOVE INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER'
    OR SO.svc_desc LIKE 'URINE%'
    )
)
```

The code I am trying to get working with the rest of it is the section that is entirely commented out. With the commented portion in the query takes a rather long time to run meaning `t>5 minutes` with no results coming back. Without that part the query returns all results in `t<2 minutes`

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What if a `COMPLETE - URINE TEST` row is followed by a `CANCEL/DISCONTINUE/SUSPEND - URINE TEST` row for the same `VISIT_ID` ? It matters ?

Comment: For `URINE` tests I don't care to much what there status is, I only want them to show up if the person also has some sort of `FOLEY CATHETER` order during their stay. So for example if I am admitted and I get a `URINE TEST` but never get a `FOLEY CATHETER` order then I should not show up.

Comment: I know optimally you'd want to add a search condition to filter out the results in the initial call, hopefully speeding up the whole process; but, if you initial query at under 2 minutes is an acceptable time, have you tried adding a simplified HAVING filter after your initial results are found, to limit the results to just what you want?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie 2 minutes is an acceptable amount of time, its nothing that has to run in 2 seconds flat, but under 3 is good. I am not familiar with proper use of HAVING() clause and therefore have not usedit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use window aggregate functions (e.g. `MAX() OVER ...`) to determine whether a `VISIT ID` row group has rows with particular `ORD DESC` values.

Basically, the pattern would be like this:

```
SELECT
  ...
  MAX(CASE WHEN [ORD DESC] = 'URINE TEST' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    OVER (PARTITION BY [VISIT ID]) AS HasUrineTest,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [ORD DESC] IN ('INSERT FOLEY', 'REMOVE FOLEY') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    OVER (PARTITION BY [VISIT ID]) AS HasInsertRemoveFoley
FROM ...
```

That would give you flag columns in every row, with identical values per visit. You would then use those flags to filter the rows on. You would need to put the entire select into a subquery, though, and use it as a derived table in order to be able to filter on the flag columns:

```
WITH flagged AS (
  SELECT
    ...
    MAX(CASE WHEN [ORD DESC] = 'URINE TEST' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (PARTITION BY [VISIT ID]) AS HasUrineTest,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [ORD DESC] IN ('INSERT FOLEY', 'REMOVE FOLEY') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (PARTITION BY [VISIT ID]) AS HasInsertRemoveFoley
  FROM  ...  -- all your joins
  WHERE ...  -- and filters
)
SELECT ...  -- repeat all the columns except the Has* flags
FROM flagged
WHERE HasUrineTest = 1
  AND HasInsertRemoveFoley = 1
;
```

You may have noticed that I used output aliases rather than underlying names or expressions in the window functions. In actual implementation, `[VISIT ID]` would probably need to be replaced with `PV.PtNo_Num`. As for `[ORD DESC]`, you could introduce a `CROSS APPLY` clause to your (sub)query and move the `[ORD DESC]` calculation there instead of where it is calculated now, something like this:

```
WITH flagged AS (
  SELECT
     ...
     x.[ORD DESC],  -- instead of the CASE; the CASE is now in CROSS APPLY
     ...
  FROM ...  -- all your joins
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN SO.svc_desc = 'INSERT FOLEY CATHETER' THEN 'INSERT FOLEY'
        WHEN SO.svc_desc = 'INSERT INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER TO GRAVITY DRAINAGE' THEN 'INSERT FOLEY'
        WHEN SO.svc_desc = 'REMOVE INDWELLING URINARY CATHETER' THEN 'REMOVE FOLEY'
        ELSE SO.svc_desc
      END AS [ORD DESC]
   ) x
)
SELECT ...
;
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I'm going to digest this first then try first thing in the am, and if it works, I have many other queries to mold this over.

Answer (score 1):

This is starting from your input table I called Data. Hopefully it's still some help.

```
    ;With Data AS (

    SELECT 123456 [Visit ID], 123 MRN, 987654 [ORD NUM], 'ACTIVE' [ORD STS], 'URINE TEST' [ORD DESC]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456 [Visit ID], 123 MRN, 987654 [ORD NUM], 'IN PROG' [ORD STS], 'URINE TEST' [ORD DESC]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456 [Visit ID], 123 MRN, 987654 [ORD NUM], 'COMPOLETE' [ORD STS], 'URINE TEST' [ORD DESC]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456 [Visit ID], 123 MRN, 987654 [ORD NUM], 'ACTIVE' [ORD STS], 'INSERT FOLEY' [ORD DESC]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456 [Visit ID], 123 MRN, 987654 [ORD NUM], 'IN PROG' [ORD STS], 'INSERT FOLEY' [ORD DESC]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456 [Visit ID], 123 MRN, 987654 [ORD NUM], 'COMPOLETE' [ORD STS], 'INSERT FOLEY' [ORD DESC]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 124578 [Visit ID], 321 MRN, 654321 [ORD NUM], 'ACTIVE' [ORD STS], 'URINE TEST' [ORD DESC]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 124578 [Visit ID], 321 MRN, 654321 [ORD NUM], 'IN PROG' [ORD STS], 'URINE TEST' [ORD DESC]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 124578 [Visit ID], 321 MRN, 654321 [ORD NUM], 'COMPOLETE' [ORD STS], 'URINE TEST' [ORD DESC]

), VisitIDs AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Visit ID] FROM Data AS DataSource
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Data WHERE Data.[Visit ID] = DataSource.[Visit ID] AND [ORD DESC] = 'URINE TEST') 
        AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Data WHERE Data.[Visit ID] = DataSource.[Visit ID] AND [ORD DESC] = 'INSERT FOLEY' )
)
SELECT * FROM Data INNER JOIN VisitIDs ON Data.[Visit ID] = VisitIDs.[Visit ID]
```